# Joined spin dupli objects don't rotate together

Tags: mesh

Aloha.  I am trying to create an object by joining several rows of other objects created using spin dupli.  Object moves along x y z axes as a single object, but when I try to rotate it the rings rotate independently or not at all.  I removed doubles and converted curves to meshes of individual rows before joining.  Any suggestions?

[image]

The rings look the same but are of differing circumference and number of pins so that object is cone shaped.  The pin in background is kernel object I spin dupli-d to create each ring.

Comment: If that is a single object, now, it has a single own origin point. Rotation (and scaling) happens depending on the configured pivot center mode in the 3d view (in the view header, the second icon to the right of the object/edit mode selection), it can be the active object (its own pivot point), median or individual origins of several obects, the 3d cursor or the bounding box.

Comment: Not sure what to make of this post, but I tried all the pivot modes to no change

Comment: Can you show at least a picture of that object, since it might be different from what I thought? If possible show the whole blender window, to let others spot settings, modes, etc. Otherwise post the .blend file (eg: using  http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: blender file is too big to upload,  sorry but I don't know how to post screenshot and can't find instructions to do so.  .

Comment: to post a screenshot, first in Blender, use CTRL + F3 to save a screenshot. Then edit the question here, and add the saved screenshot with the "image" icon or CTRL + G

Comment: Thanks.  If image doesn't help I can upload blender file to google drive for you to review

Comment: sorry, I can't download a 270Mb file... I tried something similar (with a much, much simpler result, 3 rings of spindupli cubes 35 steps x 350°)  but can't replicate. My joined "rings" of spindupli objects rotate as one object, since they really are one object... I must have misunderstood something you said.

Comment: I successfully created a similar object before by joining duplicates of a single spin dubli ring that rotated as one object.  This object is made of individually created rings using spin dupli.  Did you use duplicates of a single ring or individually created rings?

Comment: I replicated your test with cube rings successfully joining 3 rings made from individual cubes spinduplid of different circumferences and no. of steps...they all rotated together...must be something with my original object