# Object created by joining several objects doesn't rotate uniformly consistently

Tags: mesh

Aloha.

I'm experiencing a similar problem I had with a prior posting [Joined spin dupli objects don't rotate together](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42810/1853) with another object I created by joining 3 objects that doesn't rotate uniformly consistently.

I tried clearing and applying rotation of individual objects and joined objects to no avail.

I have [screen cast of defective object](https://youtu.be/obdnMVLQpiQ) as well as object by itself in blend file if you need to see them

Any ideas?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I uploaded clip of defective object in scene.  Notice the large gear stops rotating as shaft and smaller gear continue.
https://youtu.be/obdnMVLQpiQ

Comment: I'm sorry but its not very clear what you are trying to do. How are you joining your objects? they seem like two separate objects, not one. Could you upload a blender file?

Comment: Exactly the problem!  It's 3 objects--small gear, shaft, and large gear--joined using join button under tools so its supposed to be one object. I uploaded .blend file if it helps.   Thanks

[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1423" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1423/)

Comment: I just replaced this defective object in the .blend file with a similar object from another .blend file that works fine in its animation scene...and low and behold it does NOT work just like the original object...the large gear does not rotate when the shaft and smaller gear does..gotta be some defect in the scene...really bizarre

Comment: Now you have to join them together with Ctrl + J

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the precision of your model, you should improve your modeling skills and take care of your mesh.

You model needs some serious clean up, there are quite a few misplaced vertex, inverted normals, non manifold faces, overlapping geometry, etc.

There is also one unused *Copy Rotation* constraint, probably a leftover from when there were several objects

Now to the problem at hand, what you are seeing is probably an optical illusion, your model seems to be rotating at different speeds because the center is not accurately placed relative to the geometry, making the center part "wobble" in relation to the rotation center.

[image: Wrong center]

Now your geometry is really uneven and you should probably model it cleanly from scratch, but if you don't want to, just enter edit mode, select the central vertex, move the cursor to selected, exit edit mode and align objects center to the cursor position.

[image: Fix center]

Do this for all objects, although they are all slightly skewed and wont easily be totally perfectly aligned

Comment: whoa, Duarte, thank you for the detailed tutorial.  I'm still learing Blender, but for what I need precision clean up is not a priority.  But I know it's not an optical illusion.  I just tried a similar joined object from another file and same thing--it rotates like a single object for most of the scene then separates so small gear and shaft rotate while larger gear is totally stopped. So by process of eliimination it has to be something with the scene animation.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] It is an optical illusion.  I happened to keyframe a rotation rate that moved the teeth of the large gear one tooth per frame so it looked like it wasn't moving. I changed the rotation rate by trying different keyframes and it now appears to rotate.  Thanks, Stack Exchange, ie tkausl!

[Origin rotates but object does not](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55440/origin-rotates-but-object-does-not)