# Origin rotates but object does not

Tags: mesh

Baffling problem that is a follow up to unresolved problem (Object created by joining several objects doesn't rotate uniformly consistently). This object is created by joining 3 objects..large gear, shaft and small gear. Its rotation is constrained to object in scene that's hidden along with other objects. When I play scene it rotates correctly until I change direction of target object, Then the large gear appears to stop rotating while its origin (denoted by axis and widget) and the shaft and small gear resume rotating.  Here's youtube vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfXAFHCkRxE&feature=youtu.be

My Blend: [image]

Any ideas?

Comment: If you rotate something at the right speed it will appear to be stationary even though it is moving.  Try moving the key frame a little.

Comment: Object is keyframed to rotate at same constant pace in both directions..it is NOT moving

Answer (score 4):

As already said by @Xtremity in the comments, **it is rotating** but you don't notice it. Your big gear has 30 teeths, so every 12 degrees (360 / 30) one teeth. Before the short stop, you rotate by +6 degrees every frame, so half a teeth of the big wheel. After the pause however, you rotate by *12 degrees*, exactly one teeth, per frame, so you just don't *see* it rotating.

By the way, you're not rotating in the opposite direction after the stop, it just looks like it.

Rotation in frame 209:

[image: Frame 209]

Rotation in frames 210 to 230:

[image: Frame 210-230]

Rotation in frame 231:

[image: Frame 231]

You can clearly see, that before frame 210 it rotates by 6 degrees, after frame 230 by 12 degrees.

Comment: Really? So why is the rotation of the larger gear in either direction noticeable when rotated frame by frame from 190-210 and clearly not from 230-250?

Comment: Because from 190-210 it only rotates half a teeth per frame, from 230-250 a full teeth per frame. You can't see the difference since all teeth look exactly the same, so you don't notice, that after one frame, every teeth rotated to the exact position of the next teeth.

Comment: Just go in edit-mode, grab one teeth and move it outwards a bit, then play the animation again, you'll see it's actually rotating.

Comment: (sigh) that doesn't help...i need it to LOOK like it's moving during frames 230-250, just like in frames 190-210..is there any reason why it would not look like it's moving when the rotation rate is the same.

Comment: Because the rotation rate is __not__ the same!

Comment: Ah, I get it now  tkausl.  I just changed the rotation keyframes from 190-210 to match the rate of 230-250 and sure enough it appears NOT to rotate.  So I just need to find a rotation rate that works.  Thanks, ur a genius!

Answer (score 0):

Per tkausl answer, I revised scene to rotate object at same rate by changing keyframe to rotate 6d/frame in opposite direction so rotation is visible.  Also duplicated problem..gear meshes appear almost static when tooth count=frame count producing rotation of one tooth per frame..I'll avoid this now on.